# Is uuid.uuid4() safe to use on Windows with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, windows, thread-safety, python-multiprocessing, uuid

I am running a multi-process program in Python (Python 3.10)

I am using the uuid library to create a random uuid (uuid.uuid4())
The uuid documentation provided a 'is_safe' method that suppose to tell the developer if the uuid created is safe to use in a multi-process environment. [see link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html)

When running on Windows the 'is_safe' method returns 'SafeUUID.unknown'
Does anyone know if Windows generates safe UUID?

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same question as you, and I don't know the answer.

I had some code like this

```
rand_id = uuid.uuid4()
assert rand_id.is_safe == uuid.SafeUUID.safe, f"uuid.uuid4() returned a UUID object with is_safe = {rand_id.is_safe} != uuid.SafeUUID.safe"
```

which was failing that assert because `uuid4` returns `SafeUUID.unknown` instead.

What I can add is that this behavior seems to be hard wired into `uuid4`.  Here is what its implementation looks like (in the Python 3.8 used in my current venv):

```
def uuid4():
    """Generate a random UUID."""
    return UUID(bytes=os.urandom(16), version=4)
```

The key point is that by failing to supply the `is_safe` arg in that `UUID` constructor call, its default value of `SafeUUID.unknown` will be used.

This explains why we see the behavior that we do on Windows (and presumably every other OS too).

If someone has insight into why `uuid4` is coded the way it is, if it changes in later versions of Python, etc I would love to know.